# Magento 2: Pre-populate some name and address fields using KnockoutJS

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, knockoutjs, input

I would like to update the content of the firstname and surname fields on the checkout. The UI input fields already have the `value` data-bind (see below) which I'd like to target in my `js/view` file and update its value.

```
<input 
class="input-text" 
type="text" 
data-bind="
    value: value,
    valueUpdate: 'keyup',
    hasFocus: focused,
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        placeholder: label,
        'aria-describedby': noticeId,
        id: uid,
        disabled: disabled
}" 
name="firstname"
placeholder="First Name"
aria-describedby="notice-IE29P4K"
id="IE29P4K"
>
```

How would I target just the value data-bind of the firstname and surname input fields?